# How to turn Riemann sum into definite integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I'm having trouble with turning this Riemann sum into a definite integral. I'm not sure as to where to start.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{3}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\dfrac{3k/n}{(3k/n+3)^2}$$

Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaydt.png

Comment: Could you give a brief explanation ?

Comment: oh sorry! the picture didn't show up i'm a new user

Comment: I've edited post so pic shows up.

Waiting for edit to be approved

Comment: i know that 3/n is delta x but i'm not quite sure what xi + a  is in the sum. And if the lower bound a is 3 or 9.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n)$$
(for $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous).

Answer (score 1):

More explicitly,
as Luiz Cordeiro stated,
replace
$\frac1{n}$
outside the sum
by $dx$
and
$\frac{k}{n}$
by $x$
inside.

This changes
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{3}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\dfrac{3k/n}{(3k/n+3)^2}
$
into
$\int_0^1 3\dfrac{3x\,dx}{(3x+3)^2}
=\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\,dx}{(x+1)^2}
$.